# VivaGraphJS remove link

Tags: javascript, graph, webgl, vivagraphjs

I'm using vivagraphJS for drawing linked-data with webGL.
When I mouseover a node, I draw each link from this node.
And when I mouseout this node, I'd like to remove those links..
So, there is my code:

```
function removeLink(node, graph) {
     graph.forEachLinkedNode(node.id, function(linkedNode, link) {
         graph.removeLink(link);
         // I also tried this : 
         // graph.removeLink(link.fromId, link.toId);
     });
}
```

And there is how to do in vivagraph How To :

```
 g.forEachLinkedNode('nodeId', function(linkedNode, link){
    g.removeLink(link); 
 });
```

My problem is that when I mouseIn a node, link are shown correctly, but when I mouseOut from this node, nothing happens... (But I'm sure that my code is correct because there is a console.log that show me what's link is when I mouseOut and the data are correct..)

Maybe there is another solution with webGL to undraw an element...

Comment: Can you give a link to jsfiddle to reproduce this?

Comment: In fact, i call removeLink function in simpleClick on node instead of doubleClick, and it's works... I don't understand why doubleClick doesn't remove links... 
Thanks for your interest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, i call removeLink function in simpleClick on node instead of doubleClick, and it's works.